# Probability the number of coins coming up heads

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I throw a coin $n$ number of times.

> 1) What's the probability of the number of times of coming up tails is divisible
>   by $4$?
>
> 2) What's the probability that it's not divided by number $4$?

My reasoning is to tackle by going one by one.

Answer (score 0):

$$\left(\frac12\right)^n \sum \binom n k [0\le k\le n][k\equiv 0\pmod 4]$$